# How to increase area of a view without given a color or using opacity modifier?

Tags: swiftui

I have very small circle for tap but because it is small I want make it user friendly experience and increase area of tappable area, using Color.clear would deactivated this operation and using opacity modifier even with low value would be viable to eyes, so how to make this work, without using opacity modifier?

```
struct ContentView: View {
var body: some View {
    VStack {

        Circle()
            .fill(Color.white.opacity(0.05))
            .frame(width: 50.0, height: 50.0)
            .overlay(
            
                Circle()
                    .fill(Color.black)
                    .frame(width: 2.0, height: 2.0)
                
                )
            .onTapGesture {
                print("tap")
            }
     
    }
    .frame(width: 400.0, height: 400.0)
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the tappable area is only on visible content.
Use [`contentShape(_:eoFill:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/contentshape(_:eofill:)) to extend the tappable area onto the Shape you provide, like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var count: Int = 1
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Circle()
                .fill(Color.clear) // << Content can now be .clear
                .frame(width: 50.0, height: 50.0)
                .overlay(
                    Circle()
                        .fill(Color.black)
                        .frame(width: 2.0, height: 2.0)
                )
                .contentShape(Circle()) // << here!
                .onTapGesture {
                    print("tap \(count)")
                    count+=1
                }
        }
        .frame(width: 400.0, height: 400.0)
    }
}
```

(I added a counter for visible change while debugging.)

Answer (score 1):

@soundflix's answer is correct in suggesting [the `contentShape` modifier](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/contentshape(_:eofill:)). I just want to point out that you can shorten the code a bit. You don't actually need a clear shape or an overlay. You can get the same layout by applying `.frame` twice in a row:

```
struct RootView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .fill(Color.black)
            .frame(width: 2, height: 2) // child (Circle) receives this size
            .frame(width: 50, height: 50) // parent stack uses this for layout
            .contentShape(Circle())
            .onTapGesture { print("tap \(CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent())") }
    }
}
```

Comment: That is very good, if you add `.clipShape(Circle())` before `.contentShape(Circle())` that would make the tapeable area as a Circle with frame of 50X50, because right now with your code the tap area is a rect with frame of 50X50.

Answer (score 0):

```
import SwiftUI
```

struct ContentView: View {
@State var num: Int = 0

```
var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .center) {
        Text(String(num))
        Circle()
            .frame(width: 50.0, height: 50.0)
            .foregroundColor(.green.opacity(0.0000009))
            .overlay(
                Circle()
                    .fill(Color.black)
                    .frame(width: 2.0, height: 2.0)
                
                )
            .onTapGesture {
                num += 1
            }
    }
    .padding()
}
```

}

ok just give more little number to opacity
[image]

Comment: The question is to do it without using opacity modifier.